# .NET C#: How to dislay foreign key property?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, foreign-keys, code-first

I have this model called *Station* and *ServiceLevel*.
*Station* contains a foreign key called ServiceLevelId which refers to a primary key in the *ServiceLevel* table.

But I can't show the ServiceLevel properties which is a part of the Station.

I can present the station properties in the view by writing:

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
```

But it won't show the foreign object properties if I write:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ServiceLevel.Title)
```

I would really appreciate if somebody could explain me why it doesn't work.

*Station*.cs and *ServiceLevel*.cs:

```
public class Station
{
    public int StationId { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? ServiceLevelId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ServiceLevelId")]
    public ServiceLevel ServiceLevel { get; set; }
}

public class ServiceLevel
{
    public int ServiceLevelId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Merry christmas!

Comment: Test with add virtual on navigation properties : public virtual ServiceLevel ServiceLevel { get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

Your ServiceLevel property is not virtual, so EF lazy loading won't work. You have to explicity load the ServiceLevel when querying for Station object, by using Include() method. This is called Eager Loading.

```
context.Stations.Include(x=>x.ServiceLevel).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to work you can make ServiceLevel virtual by prefixing it with 'virtual' keyword. This will enable run time creation of a proxy to your POCO class so it will be available when you call for it;

```cs
public class Station
{
    public int StationId { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? ServiceLevelId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ServiceLevelId")]
    public virtual ServiceLevel ServiceLevel { get; set; }
}
```

By default your related entity is not loaded if you don't prefix it by 'virtual' keyword so your code fails.

The other way, as previous answer suggested is to Eager load it, i.e. force the related entity to be loaded. In my humble opinion this is not optimal way to go except you have some specific reason to do so.

Comment: Hi mmara. Thanks for your answer. As you mentioned, I'm trying to avoid eager loading. Sadly using the virtual keyword doesn't solve my problem. @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ServiceLevel.Title still returns nothing. Best regards.

Comment: I know you've probably checked but, have you looked in the DB and verified that the data is actually there and all the references are properly set?